# Format javascript variable to be used by Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I am sending a POST request to my Rails server.

The server is executing this code :

```
List.create!(params[:list])
```

Here is my javascript (coffeescript) call :

```
createList: (list) ->
  $$.post 'http://localhost:3000/lists.json', data, null, 'json'
```

I am trying to pass `data` formatted in a way that Rails will be able to read it. I tried creating a `var params = { "list":list }`, but I get an error

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `stringify_keys' for "[object Object]":String)
```

How can I correctly format the data passed to rails?

Answer (score 0):

```
createList: (list) ->
  $$.post 'http://localhost:3000/lists.json', JSON.stringify(data), null, 'json'
```

Comment: And how can I wrap `list` inside `data`? --> `data = "list":list` ?

Comment: `data` is nothing. I need to pass `list` (`createList`'s argument). Now, if I simply type `$$.post url, list`, I get an error on Rails because I will need to use `params` to access the list. That's why I am trying to encapsulate `list` inside a variable so that I can write `params[:list]` in Rails.

Comment: Then this, `JSON.stringify(list: list)` or `data = list: list`, etc. Please review coffeescript assignments: http://coffeescript.org/